# Java Regex to remove all full stops apart from real numbers within a text

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex to remove all `.` apart from the ones which occur in real numbers.

E.g. 
The value was 0.19 psi. The water level has to be brought to normal. Mtl.temp is going to be high..

The below regex selects all real numbers.

```
((\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)|((\+|-)?\.?[0-9]+)
```

I could do the other way wherein I could select for pattern wherein it selects `.` preceded by a word and succeed by space. But, the input test is not written in proper grammatical manner.

Comment: is .12 valid or should "." be preceded by a digit ?

Comment: .12 is also valid entry

Comment: If you want to go the exclusion way, use [`s.replaceAll("([+-]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+)|\\.", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/cdcOFl/1)

Comment: Not an answer, but I think you can simplify the regex you have to just: `(\+|-)?([0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?)`. That is, just the first part of the 'OR', but saying that the [0-9] preceding the `.` can occur 0 or more times (`*`) instead of 1 or more times (`+`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\.(?!\d)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/v09Zkp/1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\.(?!\\d)";
final String string = ".12 . 0.123 Hi.there I am .invalid.";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```